# How do I create a popup banner before login with Lightdm?

Tags: unity, login-screen, zenity

When Ubuntu was using gnome I was able to create a popup banner like the banner below before the login screen using zenity in the */etc/gdm/Init/Default*. The line of code would be like this:

```
if [ -f "/usr/bin/zenity" ]; then /usr/bin/zenity --info --text="`cat /etc/issue`" --no-wrap; else xmessage -file /etc/issue -button ok -geometry 540X480; fi
```

How can I accomplish this with Unity?

> NOTICE TO USERS
>
> This is a computer system and/or it is directly connected to
>   a local network system. It is for authorized use only. Users (authorized or 
>   unauthorized) have no explicit or implicit expectation of privacy.
>
> Any or all uses of this system and all files on this system may be
>   intercepted, monitored, recorded, copied, audited, inspected, and
>   disclosed to authorized site, Department of Energy, and law
>   enforcement  personnel, as well as authorized officials of other
>   agencies, both domestic and foreign. By using this system, the user
>   consents to such interception, monitoring, recording, copying,
>   auditing, inspection,  and disclosure at the discretion of authorized
>   site or personnel.
>
> Unauthorized or improper use of this system may result in
>   administrative disciplinary action and civil and criminal penalties.
>   By continuing to use this system you indicate your awareness of and
>   consent to these  terms and conditions of use.
>
> LOG OFF IMMEDIATELY if you do not agree to the conditions stated in
>   this warning.

Comment: This doesn't work in Ubuntu 12.04 :(

Answer (score 6):

The configuration file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf defines the available sessions. The sessions themselves are defined in /usr/share/xsessions. It should be not a problem to modify the default /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop to wrap the gnome-session command around in a script that first displays the zenity dialog, and then either exits with a nonzero status or launches the gnome-session command.

Specifically:

1. Create a file called /usr/bin/mysess.sh which contains, for example, the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   if  /usr/bin/zenity --question --text="`cat /etc/issue`" --no-wrap ; then gnome-session --session=ubuntu ; else exit 1 ; fi
   ```

   To edit this file, use

   ```
   gksu gedit /usr/bin/mysess.sh
   ```

   Also, make it executable

   ```
   sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/mysess.sh
   ```
2. Modify the file /usr/share/xsessions/ubuntu.desktop as follows:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Ubuntu
   Comment=This session logs you into Ubuntu
   Exec=/usr/bin/mysess.sh
   TryExec=unity
   Icon=
   Type=Application
   X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-session-3.0
   ```

Now, if anyone tries to log on, the person has to click "Yes" in order to log in; otherwise, it will return to the login screen.