# How do I create a popup banner before login with Cinnamon on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: lightdm, cinnamon, banner

I read the original question "[How do I create a popup banner before login with Lightdm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193357/how-do-i-create-a-popup-banner-before-login-with-lightdm)" and the answer given there was very good.

However, that covers the default "Ubuntu" session with GDM.

How can I adapt that answer to LightDM with the Cinnamon Session?