# How to show a popup after login in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, login, lightdm

I tried to follow the procedure in the answer to this question [How do I create a popup banner before login with Lightdm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193357/how-do-i-create-a-popup-banner-before-login-with-lightdm), but I just get a blank screen.  If I run my shell script on its own, I get the popup, and then some kind of error about not being able to connect to a bus or something.

I'm new to all of this - can someone please help?

I also tried calling the script from session-setup-script, which did not show the popup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I did some tweaking, I got it to work.

Tweaks included:

> - editing /etc/issue to include line breaks
> - adding /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-show-dialog.conf with contents

```
[SeatDefaults] 
session-setup-script=/usr/bin/mysess.sh
```

> - editing my shell script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
    if /usr/bin/zenity --question --text="`cat /etc/issue`" --no-wrap ;
    then
        exit 0;
    else
        exit 1;
    fi
```

> - rebooting

Comment: This works excellently even in ubuntu 16.04